# Can we configure two maven versions on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

We have two projects each using different maven and Java versions.
Currently one of these projects is already configured on Jenkins. we need to configure the other project on Jenkins as well.

Is it possible to add one more version of maven to Jenkins?
While configuring the project will it display the list of maven versions, from which I can select the required one?

Please note that I don't have admin rights and currently investigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the admin rights, you can add several Maven installation:

[image]

Next, in your Maven job, you select the relevant version:

[image]

So you have to contact your Jenkins admin to solve your pb :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Can you clearify how to get to that section you screenshotted? I would appreciate it. cant find it under "configure system"

Comment: @sharongur If you are using Jenkins 2.x, it's in the following menu: https://your.jenkins/configureTools

Comment: Here is still another wegsite that explained it: https://toolsqa.com/jenkins/jenkins-maven/

Comment: where is option maven job, i can't find in project setting maven version